# CalendarView with Buttons or ScrollViewHorizontal

Tags: android, button, scrollview, calendarview

I am trying to use the object `CalendarView` in my XML file and appears good, but I have one problem.
I want to create Two buttons to go forward and move backwards month by month.
Another option is that I could create a `ScrollViewHorizontal` to show month by month.

Can anyone help me to do this??

Thank you so much.

Comment: You want to select date as input only? Use DatePicker then.

Answer (score 0):

`CalendarView` cannot be used as it is in the way that you are asking. There are many 3rd party libraries that you can see. Here is one which is really good. https://github.com/roomorama/Caldroid